Sequoia always opens the TextMate app on the left side of the screen
Before I installed Sequoia, macOS would open the TextMate app in various places on the screen, likely depending on where I last closed it. Now, macOS always opens TextMate on the left side of the screen.
I know this has been the case for the Preview app for years, but I'm surprised that I'm now experiencing this with TextMate.
Has something changed from Sonoma to Sequoia to cause this?

Is it using the last location? Have you tried moving it, closing reopening etc?

I have. It will sometimes remember the last location, but other times it won't.
